# Error in Executing a python script when a button is clicked (JS, AJAX)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

I have this code in which I expect that if I click the connect button, `test.py` will be executed in the background. I found this solution online but I can't seem to get it working.

My Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

def main():
    os.startfile("notepad.exe")
    return "okay"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.py",
        success: function() { 
            alert("working");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("not working");
        }
    });
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot execute local python scripts through a browser.

Comment: is there anything that i can do? I need to execute a script whenever I click a this certain button in browser @MauriceMeyer

Comment: code can works only if server (Apache, Nginx) can run scripts using CGI technic but usually it can't. Normally you have to use web framework like Flask, Bottle, Django to create page and run it as server.

Comment: BTW: when you click then it sends request to server and server will try to run it, not local computer (except you run server on local computer).

Comment: @furas,thanks! btw I have configured my apache to run python by following this link http://editrocket.com/articles/python_apache_windows.html , i also installed django but i do not know how to specifically use it. I am not familiar with python at all but i need to finish this project though. and what do you mean by "except u run server on local computer"?

Comment: Flask is easier than Django for something small - you can start with few lines of code in one file like on [official page](http://flask.pocoo.org/). With Django you have to generate project with many files. Django has more functions at start but it needs to learn more things. Flask, Django has built-in server for testing code so you can run it without Apache. For small project it can be good. As for "except..." - normally we create web page on our (local) computer and run it on this computer but finally we put it on server in internet/cloud and then it will try to run `notepad.exe` on server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to call it as an CGI script your Python code should start with outputing the HTTP headers like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

def main():
    try:
        os.startfile("notepad.exe")
    except:
        print "Status: 500 Internal Server Error"
        print "Content-type: text/plain"
        print
        print "error"
    else:
        print "Status: 200 OK"
        print "Content-type: text/plain"
        print
        print "okay"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then place it in /cgi-bin/ directory of your webserver root. There comes part I'm not sure about. You has set interpreter of your Python script to "/usr/bin/python" what suggest using Linux. If that is the case you should replace "notepad.exe" with whatever is the valid editor command of your Linux distribution. Also remember to make the CGI script executable:

```
chmod +x test.py
```

On the other hand if you are using Windows, you should instead edit the first line of your script to reflect the different Windows paths, e.g.:

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe
```

You may come into some more problems with your webserver configuration if you want to use CGI on Windows, however.

When you already have CGI script working, alter the URL in your AJAX call to look for it in `/cgi-bin/`, i.e.:

```
        url: "/cgi-bin/test.py",
```

If you come to any problems with your CGI script it may be useful to use `cgitb` to debug it, bu adding following lines in your script, just before `import os`:

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```